# Is there a WmpBitmapDecoder equivelant in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, wmp

Does anyone know how to use Windows Media Photo (.wdp) in silverlight? There is the WmpBitmapDecoder class for regular wpf applications, but I don't see anything like that when I create a silverlight application.

Are there any alternative image formats that might be better or easier to use?

Comment: What is your application?  What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to have .wdp images on the server side and stream the down to the client so they can view the image in a viewer I am making. Keeping a good quality image and minimizing file size are top priorities which is why I am using .wdp.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, .wmp is not supported in Silverlight.